# How to update a private server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, updates

I have a Django web application, running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, inside of an EC2 linux instance. 
Only the load balancer is accessible to the internet, for security reasons. Deployment to the EC2 app server is facilitated by Elastic Beanstalk, but new packages added to the repository can't be installed without an internet connection.

What is the standard way to automatically update without an internet connection?

Should I just create another EC2 and use it as a proxy server? How can I configure this?

Are there any references on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) is used for that:

> You can use a network address translation (NAT) gateway to **enable instances in a private subnet to connect to the internet** or other AWS services, but prevent the internet from initiating a connection with those instances.

There are also [NAT instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) which also can be used for the same purpose. However NAT gateway is a managed and scalable service and is usually preferred over NAT instances.

Comment: Great, do you know a way to only allow the update commands (apt-get, pip install) to access the internet?